# How do I monitor health / connectivity to Blazor Server Side?

Tags: signalr, monitoring, blazor-server-side, .net-5, health-monitoring

I'm experiencing connectivity issues in my Blazor Server app hosted on premise.

I would like to perform realtime monitoring of my app on both, localhost and remotely.

I imagine something like keeping the Signal R connection open and write to log if it is interrupted.

How do I monitor health of my Blazor Server app, especially the health of Signal R Connectivity?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your infrastructure around the server-side application, you may want to consider the libraries for [health checks for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-5.0). These are not Blazor-specific, but offer a solution to monitor your application and its dependencies.

Comment: That's the endpoint, but who will be pinging it and logging the results, sending alerts, etc?